# Gradle equivalent to Maven's "copy-dependencies"?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

In Maven-land, anytime I want to simply pull down the transitive dependencies for a particular POM file, I just open a shell, navigate to where the POM is located, and run:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

And **boom**, Maven creates a `target/` directory inside the current one and places all the transitively-fetched JARs to that location.

I am now *trying* to make the switch over to Gradle, but Gradle doesn't seem to have the same feature. So I ask: **Does Gradle have an equivalent to Maven's `copy-dependencies`?**  If so, can someone provide an example? If not, would other devs find this to be a worthwhile contribution to the Gradle community?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's no equivalent of `copy-dependencies` in gradle but here's a task that does it:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5'
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'dependencies'
}
```

Is it worthwhile to do a contribution? AS You can see it's really easy to do, so I don't think so.

**EDIT**

From gradle 4+ it will be:

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.default
  into 'dependencies'
}
```

Comment: For any Gradle newcomers, take this code snippet and put it into a `build.gradle` file somewhere on your machine. Then open a shell, navigate to where you created that `build.gradle` and type `gradle copyDependencies`. After Gradle executes, a `dependencies` directory will appear with all the transitive deps inside it. You can now edit this `build.gradle` to contain whatever dependencies you like, and just make sure to delete `dependencies` before you run `gradle copyDependencies` each time.

Comment: And if you wanted to copy runtime dependencies you change `from` target to `configurations.runtime`

Comment: For *compile* both *runtime* and *compile* will be copied.

Comment: @Opal it's the opposite - for `runtime` both `compile` and `runtime` will be copied https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#configurations

Comment: I've just finished writing guide for advanced dependency management with Gradle. Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/q/31662781/746347

Comment: Sure, will have a look in a moment.

Comment: Use configurations.default - Indroneel Das' answer worked for me. He said that configurations.compile is deprecated.

Comment: What about name collision?
There is `common-1.1.1.jar` in both `android.arch.core` and `android.arch.lifecycle`. Implementation above just copied one of them :(

Comment: It copied the one that was finally resolved by the configuration resolved. Does you project use two?

Comment: It does not work for gradle 4+. See [Indroneel Das's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837586/1763602)

Comment: @Opal This works, but my requirement is copied jar file should have name like groupName.artifactName_version.jar. For eg. com.github.virtuald.curvesapi-1.07.jar

Answer (score 19):

the dependency configuration of compile is deprecated in gradle 4.x. You need to replace that with default. So the above code-snippet becomes:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5'
}
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.default
  into 'dependencies'
}
```

Comment: With the `Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1` (i.e. `Gradle 6.1.1`) this no longer works. The task does simply nothing. Running Gradle with the `--info` switch produces the following message: `Skipping task ':app:copyDependencies' as it has no source files and no previous output files.` Do you know what can be done with Gradle >= 6.1.1?

Comment: @ackh Found any solutions?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Yes, I found a solution, sort of. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558104). If you got a better approach let me know.

Answer (score 16):

This is the equivalent Kotlin DSL version (added the buildDir prefix to make it copy the dependencies in the build folder):

```
task("copyDependencies", Copy::class) {
    from(configurations.default).into("$buildDir/dependencies")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A version that works with gradle 6.8+ using Kotlin DSL

```
task("copyDependencies", Copy::class) {
    configurations.compileClasspath.get()
        .filter { it.extension == "jar" }
        .forEach { from(it.absolutePath).into("$buildDir/dependencies") }
}
```

Running `./gradlew copyDependencies` will copy all jars from compile classpath into `./build/dependencies` directory.
This can be easily modified to use a different classpath (or combine multiple classpaths) and to include other filters as needed.

Comment: I like this solution, because we also use Kotlin DSL. One question : Is it possible to define this task in the main `build.gradle.kts` and all the other modules in the solution will take it and call with the specific parameter ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to create the same task for all subprojects. Then you need to define the same task under `subprojects` block in the main `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. One more question : is it possible to pass an argument to the defined task ? Something like `task.register("copyDependencies", Copy::class, distPath: String) { ... `. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As is - probably not, `register` is a gradle function.
But you could always wrap it in a custom function that accepts a `distPath` param

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided here stopped working for me after upgrading to the Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1 that works with Gradle 6.1.1. Here's the version that I'm currently using:

```
task copyPluginDependencies {
  doLast {
    def dependencies = []
    buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { dependency ->
      dependencies.add(dependency)
    }
    dependencies.unique().each { dependency ->
      println(dependency.absolutePath)
      copy {
        from dependency.absolutePath
        into 'app/dependencies'
        eachFile { details ->
          String dependencyPath = dependency.absolutePath
          Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("(^.*caches)(.*)")
          Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(dependencyPath)
          if(regexMatcher.find()) {
            // results in the dependency path starting from Gradle's caches folder
            dependencyPath = regexMatcher.group(2)
          }
          details.setRelativePath new RelativePath(true, dependencyPath)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not elegant at all but at least it is working. Simpler versions are highly welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Task `copyAllDependencies` worked for me in `gradle-7.0`.

Here is the example to copy dependencies into `${buildDir}/output/libs`:

Add following to `build.gradle`.

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
    into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
}
build.dependsOn(copyAllDependencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to include dependencies. This could also be war instead of jar for web archives.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'my.group1:my-module1:0.0.1'
    implementation 'my.group2:my-module2:0.0.1'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.filter { it.exists() }.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```