# How can I add dependency to the gradle repository?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I made my web project in the local and it worked well. Then  I uploaded these to the server that isn't connected to the Internet. So, Some dependencies can't be found in the repository of the server. So, I want to add the dependencies to there manually. So, I tried finding every related the repository of gradle. But, it is not solved still.

The error message that I got when it build application is like the followings.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'redca-admin-deploy'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9.
     Required by:
         com.sds.redca:redca-admin-deploy:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      > No cached version of com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.9 available for offline mode.
   > Could not resolve be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1.
     Required by:
         com.sds.redca:redca-admin-deploy:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      > No cached version of be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1 available for offline mode.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

---

**My Solution** :

I added the followings in the repositories tag.

```
 flatDir {
    dirs 'gradleLib'
 }
```

And I added the jar to the folder and  it worked well.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697999/gradle-equivalent-to-mavens-copy-dependencies

Comment: I solved with the option 'flatDir'. Thanks.