# How to Make Gradle Download Dependency Libraries to Project Directory

Tags: gradle, download, dependencies

Is there a way that makes gradle download dependency libraries to the project directory, just like maven does? I know that gradle keeps its own cache in local machine directory, but how can I know what libraries will be used for my project, especially the library I defined in the build.gradle file has its own dependency?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697999/gradle-equivalent-to-mavens-copy-dependencies

Comment: Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/q/31662781/746347

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To know what libraries will be used for your project you can use dependencies task. It will help you to find out the dependencies of your module and its recursive dependencies.

If your module name is `app`, then you can try `gradle :app:dependencies` in the project directory. You'll get something like below as output.

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0                             
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0
```

Here `com.android.support:appcompact-v7:22.2.0` is dependency of the module and the one below is its recursive dependency.

If you really what to get the dependencies in your project directory, then you can create a task for it like this.

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile   
   into 'dependencies'
}
```

now you can run `gradle :app:copyDependencies` to get all the dependencies in location `<projectDir>/app/dependencies`. Note that this just give you the dependencies in your project directory and gradle is still resolving the dependencies from the local cache.

Comment: I get the following error Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container.

Comment: @IsmailIqbal that's because you need to modify your Module level gradle script, not project level