# How to "Manage transitive dependencies" with gradle?

Tags: gradle

I'd like to version control and lock down "transitive" / recursive dependencies *all the way down*, so that if I later `git checkout PRODUCT_X_Y_Z` and build it, it will use the exact same versions of all dependencies, even the ones I haven't explicitly mentioned in `build.gradle`.

How is this possible with gradle?

[Chapter 52. Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) of the docs has a "52.2.2. Manage transitive dependencies" section, describing me depending on module "A", and "A" depending on "B". Section "52.2.4. Use Dynamic Versions and Changing Modules" explains how some dependencies (direct or transitive) can yield different actual `.jar` files over time.

I've seen [gradle-dependency-lock-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin), but it [doesn't work for gradle >= 2.4](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin/issues/56#issuecomment-133279427), and that has me worried.

Is there a more gradle-native way of achieving this? I'm puzzled how anybody can tag PRODUCT_X_Y_Z without being able to reproduce it later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if locking all the versions is what you need. You can always make a `PRODUCT_X_Y_Z` tag along with a file that contains the list of all dependencies along with their versions. Generating such file in gradle is a hard task.

But, you can lock the dependencies on your own. Add all the dependencies in the `dependencies` block. Then copy all the dependencies to `lib` folder and substitute the entries under `dependencies` block with pointer to the `lib` folder. It's just a simple workaround, not a long-run solution.

Comment: "Add all the dependencies in the dependencies block" - So if I depend on a single dependency, but it in turn has 1000 dependencies of its own (or dependencies of dependencies), I have to mention and deal with the 1+1000 dependencies by myself? This is what I'd like to automate.

Comment: No, no. They will be downloaded automatically. See this Q+A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697999/gradle-equivalent-to-mavens-copy-dependencies. E.g. Try with google guice for instance.